# No module named tensorflow.python on windows 10 when I run classify_image.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I'm trying to use tensorflow to run classify_image.py, but I keep getting the same error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_image.py", line 46, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'`

Someone asked me to do a pip3 list, so I did: 
`C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip3 list Package Version ----------- ------- absl-py 0.3.0 astor 0.7.1 gast 0.2.0 grpcio 1.13.0 Markdown 2.6.11 numpy 1.15.0 pip 10.0.1 protobuf 3.6.0 setuptools 39.0.1 six 1.11.0 tensorboard 1.9.0 tensorflow 1.9.0** termcolor 1.1.0 Werkzeug 0.14.1 wheel 0.31.1 You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to add a python path, that was the only problem

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow` again.

If it said some packages can't be installed/upgrade for missing some other packages, `pip install`those packages too, and try again the first code.
That's how I solved my problem.